# Calling Data Variable from Previous Step Make.com

Tags: json

A newbie here so please be kind. I am using **make.com** to complete some **HTTP calls** and in part, they are all working very well. I am a little stuck when trying to pull a company ID from a previous steps response

I can see the block of data in the response but when I try and use it in the next step to pull the company ID it just shows as Data. I assume I need to enter something here but I am at a loss

[image]

[image]